# Отловить сочетание клавиш в консоли

Tags: c++, консоль, ввод

1) Код должен быть или кроссплатформенный, или 2а варианта кода (под Windows и Linux)

2) Мне нужно отследить, когда пользователь нажмет Shift+Enter

3) Программа консольная

Comment: А shift левый или правый?

Comment: @Александр без разницы

Comment: Хех, используй Qt

Comment: @MrBin а поподродней, как консольным приложение Qt отловить?

Comment: Посмотрите [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271784/using-qtextstream-to-read-stdin-in-a-non-blocking-fashion). В общих слова - нужно вручную читать читать из stdin. Пример выше - это socket на Linux. Также есть ссылка на [официальном форуме](https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/46256-How-to-get-keyevent-in-qt-console-application).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Можно так:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <functional>


template <typename T> void throw_if(T val, T err, const char* msg)
{
    if (val == err) { throw std::runtime_error(msg); }
}


template <typename T> void throw_if_not(T val, T ok, const char* msg)
{
    if (val != ok) { throw std::runtime_error(msg); }
}


enum class Key_t
{
    Unknown,
    Shift,
    Return,
    Esc
};


#if defined(_MSC_VER)

#include <windows.h>

Key_t to_Key_t(WORD vk)
{
    switch (vk) {
        case VK_SHIFT: return Key_t::Shift;
        case VK_RETURN: return Key_t::Return;
        case VK_ESCAPE: return Key_t::Esc;
        default: return Key_t::Unknown;
    }
}

void read_kb(std::function<bool(Key_t, bool)> key_handler)
{
    auto stdout_handle = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    throw_if(stdout_handle, INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, "could not get STD_INPUT_HANDLE");

    DWORD orig_mode;
    throw_if(GetConsoleMode(stdout_handle, &orig_mode), FALSE, "could not get console mode");
    throw_if(SetConsoleMode(stdout_handle, orig_mode | ENABLE_WINDOW_INPUT), FALSE, "could not set console mode");

    try {
        for (bool done = false; !done; ) {
            std::array<INPUT_RECORD, 128> ir;
            DWORD count;
            throw_if(ReadConsoleInput(stdout_handle, ir.data(), ir.size(), &count), FALSE, "coud not read console input");
            std::for_each(std::cbegin(ir), std::cbegin(ir) + count, [&done, key_handler](const INPUT_RECORD& r) {
                if (r.EventType == KEY_EVENT) {
                    const auto& e = r.Event.KeyEvent;
                    done = key_handler(to_Key_t(e.wVirtualKeyCode), e.bKeyDown);
                }
            });
        }
    }
    catch (...) {
        SetConsoleMode(stdout_handle, orig_mode);
        throw;
    }
    SetConsoleMode(stdout_handle, orig_mode);
}

#else

#include <termios.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <linux/kd.h>

bool is_a_console(int fd)
{
    char arg = 0;
    return (isatty(fd) && ioctl(fd, KDGKBTYPE, &arg) == 0 && ((arg == KB_101) || (arg == KB_84)));
}

int open_a_console(const char *fn)
{
    int fd = open(fn, O_RDWR);
    if (fd < 0) { fd = open(fn, O_WRONLY); }
    if (fd < 0) { fd = open(fn, O_RDONLY); }
    if (fd < 0) { return -1; }
    return fd;
}

int getfd()
{
    int fd;
    std::vector<const char*> fn = {
        "/proc/self/fd/0",
        "/dev/tty",
        "/dev/tty0",
        "/dev/vc/0",
        "/dev/systty",
        "/dev/console"
    };

    for (const auto& s : fn) {
        fd = open_a_console(s);
        if (is_a_console(fd)) { return fd; }
        close(fd);
    }

    for (fd = 0; fd < 3; fd +=1)
        if (is_a_console(fd)) { return fd; }

    throw std::runtime_error("could not get console fd");
}

Key_t to_Key_t(const char c)
{
    switch (c) {
    case 1: return Key_t::Esc;
    case 42:
    case 54: return Key_t::Shift;
    default: return Key_t::Unknown;
    }
}

void read_kb(std::function<bool(Key_t, bool)> key_handler)
{
    int fd = getfd();

    termios orig;
    throw_if_not(tcgetattr(fd, &orig), 0, "could not get attr");

    int kbmode_orig;
    throw_if_not(ioctl(fd, KDGKBMODE, &kbmode_orig), 0, "could not get KDGKBMODE");

    termios raw = orig;
    raw.c_lflag &= ~(ECHO | ICANON);
    raw.c_cc[VMIN] = 0;
    raw.c_cc[VTIME] = 1;
    tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &raw);

    throw_if_not(ioctl(fd, KDSKBMODE, K_RAW), 0, "could not set KDSKBMODE");

    try {
        for (bool done = false; !done; ) {
            char c = 0;
            if (read(fd, &c, 1) == 1) {
                done = key_handler(to_Key_t(c & 0x7F), !(c & 0x80));
            }
        }
    }
    catch (...) {
        tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &orig);
        ioctl(fd, KDSKBMODE, kbmode_orig);
        throw;
    }
    tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &orig);
    ioctl(fd, KDSKBMODE, kbmode_orig);
}

#endif

bool is_Shift_Return(const std::set<Key_t>& keys)
{
    return keys.size() == 2 &&
           keys.find(Key_t::Shift) != std::end(keys) &&
           keys.find(Key_t::Return) != std::end(keys);
}

int main()
{
    try {
        std::set<Key_t> keys;
        read_kb([&keys](Key_t key, bool is_down) {
            if (is_down) { keys.insert(key); } else { keys.erase(key); }
            std::cout
                << (is_Shift_Return(keys) ? "Shift+Return" : "Unknown")
                << " key is "
                << (is_down ? "down" : "up")
                << std::endl;
            return (key == Key_t::Esc);
        });
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e) {
        std::cout << "Error: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Проверено на Win 10, Ubintu 16.04.

В обычном режиме коды специальных клавиш (Shift, Alt, Ctrl, и т.п.) получить не удастся, т.к. ввод буферизируется и транслируется в символы (или строки). Поэтому консоль переводится в "сырой" режим (без буферизации и трансляции).

Коды клавиш: Windows - [Virtula-Key Codes](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/desktop/inputdev/virtual-key-codes), Linux - одним из способов [Keyboard input](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Keyboard_input).

Работа с консолью в Windows - все достаточно тривиально, и описано в доках [Reading Input Buffer Events](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/reading-input-buffer-events). В Linux - см. ответ и ссылки из него - https://stackoverflow.com/a/29446193/2267114, плюс код утилиты [showkey](https://kernel.googlesource.com/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/legion/kbd/+/refs/heads/master/src/showkey.c), плюс доступное описание [кодов ioctl](https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/2783).

Comment: Желательно поподробнее написать о ключевых моментах -- `KDSKBMODE` (хотя бы manpage, где описано) и структуре читаемого `read()` символа, а также, откуда числовые значения читаемых кодов. Кроме того, хотелось бы видеть поменьше "крестовости" (лямбда, исключения) в демо-примере, все же направленном на программирование системозависимой вещи, а не особенности С++.

Comment: OK/ Жаль не могу еще раз плюсануть (надеюсь, кто-нибудь мне в этом поможет -))

Comment: Интересно, но меня смущает как минимум `switch (vk)` - возникает подозрение, что ты обрабатываешь не одновременное нажатие, а последовательное?

Comment: @Qwertiy, в Linux тоже последовательные события (т.е эта программа не полностью отвечает на вопрос ТС). Но, там явно видно текущее действие (press/release) в знаковом бите, следовательно можно легко отслеживать, нажат ли еще SHIFT (а на винду я просто не смотрел).

Comment: @Qwertiy, я добавил обработку сочетаний клавиш, все достаточно тривиально.

Comment: @DmitrySokolov, а вы из под рута запускали или без Х-ов? (у меня с Х-ми `Linux avp-xubu2 4.15.0-54-generic #58-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jun 24 10:55:24 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux` только через sudo работает)

Comment: @avp, без Х-ов. С ними есть сложности, можно код `showkey` посмотреть, как там пытаются, режимы разные попробовать.

Comment: @DmitrySokolov, `std::set<Key_t> keys;` -- это дань C++? Там ведь достаточно 128 бит (пара `uint64_t` -- разумный компайлер поместит в 2 регистра)

Comment: @avp, если только сочетания будут из двух клавиш, то да - достаточно. А так можно любые отлавливать, в принципе.

Comment: @DmitrySokolov, почему только 2-х? Press -- установили бит в 1, Release -- сбросили. Набор единичек показывает какие клавиши сейчас нажаты. ЕМНИП в Х-ах  поддерживают набор нажатых в данный момент "модификаторов" (Ctl, Shift, Alt и т.п.) и при нажатии клавиши возвращают (посылают event всем кто "подписан")  ее код и текущую маску модификаторов.

Comment: @avp, по биту на клавишу? В принципе - да, но это уже не С++ way.